# Drag file from Program and Drop file to anywhere (Ex Desktop etc) using gtk#

Tags: c#, ubuntu-16.04, gtk#, gtk2

I tried to Drag a file from my application to the desktop.

I am need to set **Drag.SourceSet** to program. I do not know, how to set **Drag.DestSet** for Desktop

The below example is useful for me while file Darg file from desktop to Drop at my application.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273471/drag-and-drop-files-into-program](http://Drop%20file%20from%20anywhere%20to%20Application)

Can you please help me on this.
Thanks